# Is upgrade android app via ADB is force close the app?

Tags: android, adb, upgrade

I'm not sure my assumption is correct,

I have my installed app with version 1.0.
After I upgrade the app from ADB:

> adb install -r myappv2.apk

The app version 2.0 is installing.
Do the app version 1.0 was force closed by system?

Comment: install -r is update, keeping app preferences and databases and removing old apk.  What is exact issue in your case?

Comment: I know its update. But does it close the app while installing the new one?

Comment: yes. it will be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is correct. The app needs to be closed by the system in order to update it, either with ADB or via the Play Store.

This can lead to very odd bugs in apps that use `WebView`. If your app has a `WebView` open on the screen at the same time that Google Play decides to update the System Webview APK, your app will crash.